# Mutithreading Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

Synchronization works well with the below code.

```
  public class Main implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(m);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
 }

 // Synchronization isn't working here.

 public class Main implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Main());
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

This question was asked in an interview. I was a bit confused about this so I'm trying to understand why synchronization isn't working with the second code snippet. Can anybody explain me why synchronization won't work with the second code snippet ?

Answer (score 6):

Because synchronization is applied for if you are working on single object.

In first case you have single runnable object of Main i.e. `m`

In second case you have independent objects of Main.

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Main()); // independent objects for each thread
    t.start();
}
```

---

**Explaination:**

If you see the code you will find below line

```
synchronized (this) {
```

`this` refers to the object itself. So lock is applied based on this object. So in case of multiple Main class object they work independently where as in single object synchronization is applied for that object only.

---

For more information refer : [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Code from the documentation

```
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) { // lock is acquired using lock1 object 
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) { // lock is acquired using lock1 object 
            c2++;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you can call both the methods `inc1()` and `inc2()` using single object at same time because lock is acquired on different objects. This will help you understand it better.

So in your case lock is acquired on `this`(object itself). So whenever you have multiple object then it will work independently and when you have single object then it will work synchronously.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit ? why is it like that ?

Comment: In first case, one instance of Main is shared by multiple threads where as in second case each thread having separate copy of Main and
 each thread executed independently.

Comment: Thanks Naman. But still its not clear to me. What happens when I extend thread class and do the same ? In that case also we are creating new object each time right.

Comment: I have added example with documentation link. Hope it helps you understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two objects here.

`synchronized(this)` block will synchronize access to the same object if multiple threads try to access it.

Comment: `synchronized(foo)` does not prevent other threads from _accessing_ `foo`.  It only prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.

Comment: Also, not creating two objects:  The second example creates _hundreds_ of objects.

Comment: That is what I mean when I say "synchronize access to the object". Can't understand the reason for vote down

Comment: FYI the loop runs two times, thats why I said 2 objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
 synchronized (this)
```

"this" is the current object instance. In the first example, instance of Main class is created before invoking the thread and same instance is used. Therefore synchronization works. 
But in the second example, in each iteration of the loop in main(), new instance of Main is created. synchronized(this) will not work because there are multiple instances of Main class.

Answer (score 1):

in Java `syncronized(object)` is effectively using `object` as an exclusive lock for the code block within `syncronized`. It may be more obvious why the second version doesn't work if we make the lock explicit, and observe how many instances of the lock get created in each case:

```
 public class Lock {
 }

 public class Main(Lock lock) implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        correct()
        incorrect()
    }

    public static void incorrect() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            //New lock created each iteration
            Main m = new Main(new Lock())
            Thread t = new Thread(m);
            t.start();
        }
    }

     public static void correct() {
     //One lock used for all iterations
      Main m = new Main(new Lock())
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
            Thread t = new Thread(m);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: But what happens when I extend thread class and do the same ? that's where I am confused.

Comment: Only when we need to create a specialized form of thread. But I'm just trying to understand this synchronization.

Comment: `Synchronized(object) { code }` just means that when two threads try to access `code` concurrently, one has to wait for the other, so long as the have the same instance of `object`. It doesn't matter if you're using `Runnable` or extending `Thread`, the same principle applies.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Synchronization isn't working here.

 public class Main implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Main());
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

In above example there are 3 threads and 3 Main objects, each thread is taking a lock on different Main object so synchronization will not work.For synchronization to work we should have all threads to take a lock on the single object. Here 3 threads are not taking the lock on a single object but 3 different objects. Each thread is taking a lock on each main object which is not shared among threads. In Thread t = new Thread(m); all threads take a lock on single Main(m) object.

Answer (score 0):

I would have answered that question with a question of my own:

What do you mean, it doesn't *work*?

The first example serializes the `System.out.println()` calls and, for the reasons given in several of the other answers here, the second example doesn't serialize the calls, but so what?

`System.out` is a `java.io.PrintWriter`, and `PrintWriter` is inherently thread-safe.  Neither of the two examples *needs* synchronization at all.